# Is it possible to create and edit documents in SharePoint from an iPad?

Tags: 2010, mobile, apple-ios

I've seen SharePlus out there, but I don't think it allows for editing of documents and creating documents seems more difficult than it should be.  Has anyone found a simple complete solution for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need a 3rd party app.

I have never used this nor do I work for the company: http://www.moprise.com/

I heard about it at a SharePoint Saturday event that I attended recently. The person who told me about it had very nice things to say. But I cannot vouch for it myself.

Since Office for iPad has come out this answer has changed:

[Open a site in SharePoint Online on an iPhone or iPad](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/open-a-site-in-sharepoint-online-on-an-iphone-or-ipad-HA103702710.aspx)

[Use the OneDrive for Business app on an iPhone or iPad](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/use-the-onedrive-for-business-app-on-an-iphone-or-ipad-HA104005688.aspx)